# C# Web Method: Ensure a reply within a time limit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous, asmx

My web service is like this:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public clsReponse MyWS(string a, string b, string c) {
  clsReponse reply = doSth( a, b, c );
  return reply;
}

public clsReponse doSth(string a, string b, string c) {
  // Call other web service and hard disk I/O (i.e. write log files)
}

public class clsReponse() {
  public bool success { get; set; }
  public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

I know that the client call `MyWS` has set a 60 second timeout, but I want to reply within 30 seconds. If `doSth()` hasn't done its work within 30 seconds, I want to reply to the client first, while letting it finish its work.

I'm thinking of setting a timer in `MyWS()`, changing `doSth()` to an `async` method. But first, I'm not sure if that means every request will have its own timer?
Second, I searched the internet, and it seems `async`/`await` should not use in web methods?

I'm so confused. Is there a better way to do it?

---

Thank you for edit and comments!
I do expect to reply a message like "Taking too long" to client, but I'm not ready for second endpoint. For now, I just want to write the  process of `doSth()` into log file. So there's no output when the method is done.

---

This might be the answer:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public clsReponse MyWS(string a, string b, string c) {
  float m_state = 0;
  clsReponse reply = null;
  Task task = Task.Run( () => { reply = doSth( a, b, c ); } );
  do {
    if( task.IsCompleted )
    return reply;
    m_state += (float)1000 / 1000;
    Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
  } while( m_state < 30 );
  return reply = new clsReponse(){ success = false; msg = "Timeout." };
}
```

Please answer if there is a better way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: You need to explain a few things first. If the doSth() method doesnt complete in 30 secs, then you want to continue it to process while send a dummy/some reply back. But what happens to the processed output after method is done? Will the first API call register a callback in case its going to get timedout.

Comment: The problem is that web-ish stuff relies on a request-response protocol; when someone calls your endpoint, you need to respond once. You can't respond again until they make another request. One way to cope with that is to have your endpoint respond either with the real response or with a response that says "hey, this is taking too long, call me back later and ask for an update using this token". Then you have a second endpoint that takes a token and either gives the answer or asks for more time. It's not a simple design, but it's doable

Comment: @Flydog57: That would be a good answer to post, imho.